# Cannot install eclipse due to broken packages

Tags: package-management, eclipse

Trying to install eclipse, I get the following error:

```
XXX:~$ sudo apt-get install eclipse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 eclipse : Depends: eclipse-jdt (>= 3.8.0~rc4-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: eclipse-pde (>= 3.8.0~rc4-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have no idea how to solve it. I'm quite new to Ubuntu, but I don't think that I'm using a unstable distribution. But I have added the repository which is required to install Tomcat7. Could that cause the problem?

Comment: Can you include the output of `sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde`?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, all you got to do it paste this in your bash-terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde eclipse-platform* libtomcat7-java
```